# How should I indicate a screen shot is a screen shot?

Tags: support

Sometimes when writing a question, I find it useful to paste in a screen shot.

This is to give a visual indication of the problem.

I do understand that searchable text should also be used to describe the problem.

My question is, how should I show that screen shot is a screen shot? So that at first glance it is clear that it is a screen shot and not part of the question text?

Here I am pasting in an example screen shot of one attempt I made in GitHub

[image: Screen shot hopefully demonstrating the issue]

Comment: Hopefully the addition of an example screen shot shows why it is important to delimit that it is just an example screen shot. Indicating the meta-ness of this meta question.

Comment: Are you using GH as an example but you really want to know how to do it on SO or are you asking what to do on GH?

Comment: Both SO and GH would be great.

Comment: Not sure whether answering for GH is on topic here. I've answered for SO since that's in scope. I'm not sure if that styling is used or common on GH, though.

Comment: -1 for lack of freehand circles.

Comment: @Will Can you explain more. What is a freehand circle?

Comment: @KirstenGreed it is a meme: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/158100 
 (and mentioned in the [Glossary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms/40354#40354) ) and FYI: there are no down votes on your question at the moment I post this. That is part of the joke.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On Stack Exchange / Stack Overflow the recommendation is to put the screenshot in a quote.

> [image: screenshot of this question in a mobile view]

This places a yellow border around the image to set it apart. This is mentioned in this [Meta Stack Exchange question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306037/284336) about when to use quote markup.

Answer (score 6):

Some suggestions:
**Put a border around the image**
By putting a border around an image, you are setting it apart from the rest of the text. Until someone can find a way to put borders in a text-only post, it becomes obvious that an image is present.

Edit: as stated in another answer, you can put the image in a quote to add a border.
**Draw shapes on the image**
I feel this one is self-explanatory. Arrows, boxes, freehand circles, anything to indicate that this isn't just text.
**"This is a screenshot"**
Add a short sentence stating something like "here is a screenshot of the issue" to make sure people can tell when the image starts. Prepending your text with `#` makes it big and bold.

It's hard to miss:

## This is a screenshot